# Generalize a specialized JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

This is a question about *Multiple Checkbox Select/Deselect Using JQuery*:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/multiple-checkbox-select-deselect-jquery-tutorial-example/

which has the functionality of selecting multiple items from a list to process them. The Online Demo is at:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/multiple-checkbox-select-deselect/jquery-select-multiple-checkbox.html

I've extended the demo to include several groups, and have made the sample JQuery JavaScript function to work for one case, the BlackBerry one. The working code is at http://jsfiddle.net/jLx5z99q/3/.

In it, this is the specialized function that I want to generalize:

```
$(function () {
    $("#BlackBerry").click(function () {
        $('.case_blackberry').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $(".case_blackberry").click(function () {
        if ($(".case_blackberry").length == $(".case_blackberry:checked").length) {
            $("#BlackBerry").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#BlackBerry").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

I want to generalize it so that the `"#BlackBerry"` and `".case_blackberry"` are two parameters to the function, so that I can call it several times to cover other groups as well.

I'm not a JavaScript developer. Please help.

UPDATE:

I've posted the full working html source code at http://pastie.org/10278464.

Also, FYI, this full working html source code is generated *automatically* by [easygen](https://github.com/suntong001/easygen) with [this](https://github.com/suntong001/easygen/blob/master/test/html-Checkbox-Group.tmpl) template. This html test code is the reason that I wrote [easygen](https://github.com/suntong001/easygen), to make it easy to write whatever test case whatever the way I like. Hope it will help someone else too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define some specific attributes.

Try this fiddle.

`Example Fiddle:`: http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/2acnLzzw/3/

Comment: wow, the code is beyond my comprehension so I tried it last, but, WOW, it works amazingly. Now trying to understand it... I think I've made a mistake in my html code -- If I'm not using `<input type="checkbox" class="case_blackberry" name="case" value="BlackBerry Bold 9650">` but `<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case_blackberry" value="BlackBerry Bold 9650">` instead, do you still need to define that extra data-type field? I've switched them for you, in case it'd help: http://jsfiddle.net/2acnLzzw/1/. Thanks

Comment: Figured out what you did. This is after code clean up, and is still working: http://jsfiddle.net/2acnLzzw/2/. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I figured out the html part but am still not able to figure out how the JavaScript does the job. care to explain a bit please? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
function bindMulti( parent, children ) {
    parent.click(function () {
        children.attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
    children.click(function () {
        if (children.length == children.filter(':checked').length) {
            parent.attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            parent.removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
};
```

Use like this:

```
bindMulti($('#select_all'),$('.children'));
bindMulti($('#BlackBerry'),$('.case_blackberry'));
```

Comment: Thanks @psalmody, this look the closest to what I was asking for. However, when I tried it out, it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/jLx5z99q/8/. Anything I've missed? Thanks

Comment: try again - sorry the `$('#BlackBerry')` selecter is case sensitive (I originally put `Blackberry` instead of `BlackBerry`)

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining your current's code logic and flow and element identification, you can do:

```
$(function () {
    $(".case_subgroup_all").click(function () {
        $('.case_'+$(this).attr('id').toLowerCase()).attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
    $(".case_blackberry").click(function () {
        if ($(".case_blackberry").length == $(".case_blackberry:checked").length) {
            $("#BlackBerry").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#BlackBerry").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
```

});

I've also added `case_subgroup_all` to your 'check all' checkboxes, in order to call your event handler.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLx5z99q/5/

Comment: This looks to be the most promising solution, @Prusprus. However, at its current stage, the following functionality is missing: *"suppose user select all the checkbox one by one then the selectall checkbox should be automatically gets selected. And if user click selectall first and then unchecks any of the checkbox, then the selectall also should be unchecked automatically."* Could you make it fully working please?